# How can I redirect to homepage window.location= 'URL'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to redirect my users back to my homepage. I've written the following JavaScript code, but it isn't working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var app = {
  paused: 0,
  init: function() {
    // add full screen object
    $('body').prepend('<div id="cover"></div>');
    //if mouse moves hide object
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
      $('#cover').hide();
    })

    // check every 5 seconds to see if object has been hidden by mouse move
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      if ($('#cover').is(":hidden")) {
        $('#cover').show();
        app.paused = 0;
      } else {
        app.paused += 5;
      }
      //if mouse hasn't moved, go back to main page
      if (app.paused >= 15) {
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
      }
      console.log(app.paused);
    }, 5000);

  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  app.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems to be working. Did you insert jquery to project?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Are you including jQuery before this code, or after?

Comment: Yes, I inserted jquery in the index.php at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine as long as you are running the orignal and redirected pages on the same domain.

In above snippet, the iframe's src is `https://stacksnippets.net` which is different from `google.com`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Since you only want a redirect to your homepage->

```
if(app.paused >= 15){
     window.location = '/';
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(app.paused >= 15){
       window.location = '/';
        }
```

This worked!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // app.init();
 });
```

app.init() was also commented out. Uncommented it and it works now.